# How to have "local" numbering for amsmath align environments?

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

I am trying to re-start the numbering in amsmath align environment. My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The following equations should be numbered $(1)$ and $(2)$.
\begin{align}
7x - 15y &= 2 \\
x + 2y &= 3 
\end{align}

The following should continue from the above numbering:
\begin{align}
4x - 5y &= 2 \\
6x + 7y &= 3 
\end{align}

But the following should be numbered $(1)$ and $(2)$ and not continued from the above.
\begin{align}
7x - 6y &= 4 \\
5x + 7y &= 3 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image: Output of MWE]

I want the equations numbered (5) and (6) to be numbered (1) and (2).

Ideally, I would like the numbering scheme to be "contained" to a given set of related equations, so that once I reset the numbering counter (say), it should not infect the global numbering scheme.

How do I make this happen, please?

Comment: I am creating a problem set and writing up the answers for each problem. In each problem, there are a lot of throwaway equations that I will not need to refer to later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The usual way to have a local numbering scheme is with `subequation` although you can save and reset the main `equation` counter if you prefer, both forms shown here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcounter{saveeqn}
\begin{document}

The following equations should be numbered $(1)$ and $(2)$.
\begin{align}
7x - 15y &= 2 \\
x + 2y &= 3 
\end{align}

The following should continue from the above numbering:
\begin{align}
4x - 5y &= 2 \\
6x + 7y &= 3 
\end{align}

But the following should be numbered $(1)$ and $(2)$ and not continued from the above.
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
7x - 6y &= 4 \\
5x + 7y &= 3 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

but you could do
\setcounter{saveeqn}{\value{equation}}\setcounter{equation}{0}
\begin{align}
7x - 6y &= 4 \\
5x + 7y &= 3 
\end{align}
\setcounter{equation}{\value{saveeqn}}

and then
\begin{align}
7x - 6y &= 4 \\
5x + 7y &= 3 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is precisely the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX-SE! I personally would not want to do that. However, if you really want to do that, you could use `\tag`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The following equations should be numbered $(1)$ and $(2)$.
\begin{align}
7x - 15y &= 2 \\
x + 2y &= 3 
\end{align}

The following should continue from the above numbering:
\begin{align}
4x - 5y &= 2 \\
6x + 7y &= 3 
\end{align}

But the following should be numbered $(1)$ and $(2)$ and not continued from the above.
\begin{align}
7x - 6y &= 4 \tag{1} \\
5x + 7y &= 3 \tag{2}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I am curious though: why wouldn't you want to do that?

Comment: @ARV Because IMHO it defeats the purpose of equation numbering. If you ever want to say sth like "As shown in equation (1)", how will the reader know what is meant by that?

Comment: But this is a common scenario, isn't it? Say you have a section with a lot of "temporary" equations, like a problem in a problem set for simultaneous equations. It is understood that (1) refers to the equation in the problem being discussed. It'd then be desirable to have an independent counter for each problem.

Comment: @ARV For that purpose there is `\muberwithin{equation}{section}` and the like. You could also tag these equations `1'` and `2'`, say. I just would like to argue that one should avoid tagging two equations identically.